# PHP curl file uppload

Tags: php, curl, upload

Hi I need help to create curl sent fie script.
I have two directories: 'from' & 'to' in my localhost
My file is in directory 'from' and my filename is 'test.docx'

I want to sent that file in directory 'to' file can have same name test.docx
And I have next example code:

```
$path='from/test.docx';
$size=filesize($path);
$info=pathinfo($path);
$name=$info['filename'];
$open=fopen($path, "rb");
$content=fread($open,$size);
fclose($open);
$ar=array('content'=>$content,'fname'=>$name);
$input=array('input'=>$ar);
$datas=json_encode($input);
$ch=curl_init('localhost/to/accept.php');
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas);
curl_setopt($chs,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($datas))
);


$responses=curl_exec($chs);
print_r($responses);
```

My accept file is next:
accept.php

```
$initc = CJSON::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($initc);
```

but i get null of the content my result is next:

```
array (size=1)
  'input' => 
    array (size=2)
      'content' => null
      'fname' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Maby other important information is that i was chunk one file from 10 kb to onother 10 files with one kb and just example one of that smaller files is file test.docx
Do you know any sollution, i was read some sollutions but I don't understand them can anyone give me explonation with my example?

Comment: are there any error messages in the log ? Have you verified your php settings ? Max upload, execution time etc..

Comment: Your code send usual `POST` request, not uploading. You have to read manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Thank you, I will try again i will sent you feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($chs, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```